# Update displayed table after change without refreshing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table displayed on my site , a user can click on the ID of a row and a colorbox (jquery) pop is displayed, from here they can update the selected row.

When they click save the row is successfully updated in the DB. 
When the popup is closed the previously displayed table is still there showing the old data.
If I hit f5 it will update as expected. Is there anyway to do this dynamically , so the page reloads after the user has click save ? 
I dont want them to have to manually reload the page.

EDIT - Adding code.

Colobox popup function

```
    <script>
$(function ()
    {
    $(".editenq").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:525, innerHeight:400});    
    $(".addenq").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:525, innerHeight:400});    
 })
    </script>
```

Further down the user clicks on the enquiry ID to edit it

```
echo "<td><a class= 'editenq' href=\"editenq?enqid={$row['enqid']}\">{$row['enqid']}  </a></td>";
```

The pop up is just a basic form, pre-populated from DB and users can make changes then click save.

I want then after closing the pop the original table shows the updated data

thanks

Comment: You can use jQuery ajax to update the table data, or even just a `html()` to update the element. Or you can actually reload the page with JavaScript if you want. `location.reload();` after they hit save.

Comment: The save is on the popup though, not the original page displaying the data

Comment: Shouldn't matter. Can you post your code? Can't really do much without seeing how your popup is handled or what happens when you press save.

Comment: Ok ... will post it shortly

Comment: you can either use ajax to reload the table asynchronously or just use javascript to change the values of the row when the popup is closed (as you should be able to get those values from your popup form)

Comment: What is the code that is used to handle pressing the save button?

Comment: The save button is just php to do the UPDATE in SQL, then printf a success message (still within popup)

Comment: Since I can't see the code still. Maybe you can add to you button html `onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"` That is the fast if you just want to refresh.

Comment: That seems to be refreshing the popup box ... the save button/form is in side the popup box. The original page needs to refresh after the pop has been closed

Comment: Then try this.. `onClick='window.opener.location.reload();'`

Comment: No change, I still need to manually refresh the page :-(

Comment: Gary, when you use AJAX as suggested, you can use the "success" function in the AJAX call to update any UI elements on your page without refreshing. And it doesn't matter where you trigger the AJAX from – from within colorbox is certainly no showstopper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then, this should work using colorbox callback. You could to it to the other colorbox too if needed, the one with `.addenq`.

```
   <script>
$(function ()
    {
    $(".editenq").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:525, innerHeight:400,onClosed:function() { location.reload(true); }});    
    $(".addenq").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:525, innerHeight:400});    
 })
    </script>
```